# PHPUnit and specking method aliasing

Tags: php, phpunit

Consider this class

```
class Foo {      

  public function alias_method($input) {
    return $this->actual_method($input);
  }

  public function actual_method($input) {
    # Do something
  }
}
```

Now, I have already written tests that verify the behavior of `actual_method`, so for `alias_method`, all I want to ensure is that it calls `actual_method` with `$input`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Most likely this kind of test will be superfluous and therefore not only waste but also creates a burden as you maintain the code. I would suggest to no test it (One could even start to question that this is a unit-test at all). However, if you only want to ensure it's called with input, you can use a mock for that. An example is with the PHPUnit documentation, it's pretty straight forward: http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

Comment: Do you have a code example? I am not interested in creating a double. I am interested in setting up a method invocation expectation.

I know you could argue that it seems superflous, but I am writting a general purpose library and want to emphasize the presence of the alias method as part of the public API.

Comment: I usually find myself agreeing with most of @hakre's comments, but on this occasion I don't. Sorry :) Your alias_method() is public and therefore you need to ensure it works as expected, so it needs testing. Changes to your code in the future could break one or the other of these methods. For example, you may make a change in the alias by mistake and not in the actual method, unit tests would flag this up. I would question the need for the alias, rather than the need to test it, but I don't know your use case.

Comment: @vascowhite: While on the letter-of-code basis what you say might not be wrong, in terms of what the test says if it fails (for what you actually test), so the benefit of it, I just question the use. As it's exemplary, I've given an example in an answer how it could be done, as I don't want to question the OPs motivation when answering. But I've left a note by the comment that I smell the test *might* be superfluous. E.g. it seems to be a design issue to alias the method in the first place.

Comment: @hakre I saw that, your answer is probably the most sensible solution in the circumstances.

Comment: Updated again and added comments into the code, please note the very similarty to ***Example 9.11: Testing that a method gets called once and with a specified argument*** which by the wording seems pretty much you're asking for: http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

Answer (score 0):

As you've asked for a code-example, this is a PHPUnit test method body that has your expectation set-up already:

```
/**
 * TODO Find out whether or not the test is necessary
 *
 * Note: This example is a slight adoption from the Observer/Subject
 *       mock example from PHPUnit docs:
 *       Example 9.11: Testing that a method gets called once and with 
 *       a specified argument
 *
 * @link http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html
 *
 * @test
 */
public function methodIsCalledWithInputArgument()
{
    // Create an Input object to test with as method argument
    $input = new Input();

    // Create a mock for the Foo class,
    // only mock the actual_method() method.
    $foo = $this->getMock('Foo', array('actual_method'));

    // Set up the expectation for the actual_method() method
    // to be called only once and with the argument $input
    // as its parameter.
    $foo->expects($this->once())
       ->method('actual_method')
       ->with($this->identicalTo$(input))
    ;

    // Call the alias_method() method on the $foo object
    // which we expect to call the mocked Foo object's
    // actual_method() method with $input.
    $foo->alias_method($input);
}
```